# jQuery Messi modal window plugin

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to configure the jQuery Messi (modal window) plugin.

I've checked the documentation and examples but there is no way I can get the Close button to center in the modal window.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: provide some code, i'm pretty sure this can be achieved with css fairly easy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this line to your `CSS` file and try again.

```
.messi-footbox { text-align: center; }
```

Comment: Hey, Emre Erkan ... thank you! This worked perfectly. Button now centered. Your help much appreciated.

Comment: @RussellTimms You should click the green accept checkmark to the left of the answer and upvote the response if it answers your question!

Comment: @Cymen Thanks for hint, I'm new to this. Have accepted answer. I haven't accrued enough points to upvote the answer.